# How to make the code flow without closing the VTK render window?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visualization, vtk

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, VTK 5.6 and configure my projects without using CMake.

I'm dealing with numerical computing and want to generate several plots during the runtime using VTK. Starting with the line plot example given in the VTK web page I managed to generate the plot that I want. The problem is that the code doesn't continue without closing the plot window.

From my "main.cpp" file, I send the command to a header file, where the VTK procedure is initiated.

```
residualPlotter(x,xdim1d);
```

"residualPlotter" is the function that generates the plot. It's given below:

```
int residualPlotter(double* res, int size)
{

  // Create a table with some points in it
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkTable> table = 
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkTable>::New();

  vtkSmartPointer<vtkFloatArray> arrX = 
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkFloatArray>::New();
  arrX->SetName("X Axis");
  table->AddColumn(arrX);

  vtkSmartPointer<vtkFloatArray> arrF = 
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkFloatArray>::New();
  arrF->SetName("Function");
  table->AddColumn(arrF);

  // Fill in the table with some example values
  table->SetNumberOfRows(size);
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
  {
    table->SetValue(i, 0, i);
    table->SetValue(i, 1, res[i]);
  }

  // Set up the view
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkContextView> view = 
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkContextView>::New();
  view->GetRenderer()->SetBackground(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  view->GetRenderWindow()->SetSize(800,600);

  // Add multiple line plots, setting the colors etc
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkChartXY> chart = 
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkChartXY>::New();
  view->GetScene()->AddItem(chart);
  vtkPlot *line = chart->AddPlot(vtkChart::LINE);
  line->SetInput(table, 0, 1);
  line->SetColor(0, 100, 0, 255);
  line->SetWidth(1.75);


  // Set up an interactor and start
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> renderWindowInteractor = 
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();
  renderWindowInteractor->SetRenderWindow(view->GetRenderWindow());
  renderWindowInteractor->Initialize();
  renderWindowInteractor->Start();


  return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

So, I want the code to continue without the need to close the window. How should I modify the code?

Thank you all.

Comment: You can reference the solution here! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136711/vtk-window-thread-from-main-thread-c/33363593#33363593

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to render the plot, do something else, update and render again you can skip the renderWindowInteractor code, and simply call

```
view->Render();
```

This will render the plot with the data you supplied, and control will return to your code. You can continue doing this and call Render() on the view whenever you want to see an updated chart.

Comment: thank you very much. When I do that the plot window pops up instantly but then again vanishes in a moment as the code goes on. is there a way to make it stay on the screen?

Comment: @Marcus , I have the same issue. my window also gets vanished when the code goes on. Did you fix that? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry - forgot about the question. If you want the window to persist you must start an interactor. You then need to fire a timer event, or something similar, that can trigger your updates of the chart. Any GUI needs to go into an event loop in order to persist, VTK is the same.

Comment: @MarcusD.Hanwell Could you please suggest me an example on how to do this? I have tried setting vtk renderwindowinteractor, but the window gets crashed when closing. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: I am facing a similar problem. Did you find a solution yet?

Answer (score 2):

Marcus D. Hanwell mentioned a timer event at the comment. There is a code at a [VTK example section](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Utilities/Timer). For me, I modified the snippet;

```
// Initialize must be called prior to creating timer events.
renderWindowInteractor->Initialize();

// Sign up to receive TimerEvent
vtkSmartPointer<vtkTimerCallback> cb = vtkSmartPointer<vtkTimerCallback>::New();
renderWindowInteractor->AddObserver(vtkCommand::TimerEvent, cb);

int timerId = renderWindowInteractor->CreateRepeatingTimer(100);
std::cout << "timerId: " << timerId << std::endl;


renderWindowInteractor->Start();
```

and I changed the vtkTimerCallback class at the sample code (in here, the background color keep being changed);

```
class vtkTimerCallback : public vtkCommand
{
public:
    static vtkTimerCallback *New()
    {
        vtkTimerCallback *cb = new vtkTimerCallback;
        cb->TimerCount = 0;
        return cb;
    }

virtual void Execute(vtkObject *vtkNotUsed(caller), unsigned long eventId, void *vtkNotUsed(callData))
{
    if (vtkCommand::TimerEvent == eventId)
    {
        ++this->TimerCount;
    }
    /* this section will be excuted */
    cout << this->TimerCount << " " << "This is from vtkTimerCallback" << endl;
    background_color = (double) rand() / RAND_MAX;
    cout << background_color << endl;
    renderer->SetBackground(background_color, background_color, background_color); 
    renderWindow->AddRenderer(renderer);
    renderWindow->Render();
    /* ----- */
}
private:
    int TimerCount;
};
```

I declared the renderer and renderWindow as global variable, so the window change the window in the main section.

Answer (score -1):

I added the grid to a vtkActor as follow:

> vtkSmartPointer actor_grid = vtkSmartPointer::New();
>
> vtkSmartPointer chart = vtkSmartPointer::New();
>
> renderer->AddActor(actor_grid);

This works well since it is not associated with an interactor.

Thanks.